# Differences of the ord() function between Python 2.7 and 3.9

Tags: python, xor, ord, binascii

Good morning people!
I've been trying to convert [this code](https://github.com/rf-peixoto/Studies/blob/main/Code/Python/Cryptography/xorp2.py) written in Python 2 to Python 3.It's a simple function to encrypt strings using XOR. What I have so far:

```
import binascii

def encrypt(content: str, key: str) -> str:
    key_id = 0
    xored = ""
    for c in content:
        xored += chr(ord(key[key_id % len(key)]) ^ ord(c))
        key_id += 1
    return binascii.hexlify(xored.encode())

def decrypt(content: str, key: str) -> str:
    key_id = 0
    xored = ""
    for c in binascii.unhexlify(content):
        xored += chr(ord(key[key_id % len(key)]) ^ ord(c))
        key_id += 1
    return binascii.hexlify(xored.encode())
```

The code in Python 2 works perfectly, but when testing the code above *(in Python 3)*, I'm having problems decoding messages. *(The encrypt() function seems to be working perfectly.)* The following error happens:

```
>>> encrypt("foo", "123")
b'575d5c'
>>> decrypt(b"575d5c", "123")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    decrypt(b"575d5c", "123")
  File "/home/user/Code/Python/xorcrypt.py", line 15, in decrypt
    xored += chr(ord(key[key_id % len(key)]) ^ ord(c))
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

I checked both documentation, but couldn't identify any difference in versions: [ord() in Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord) and [ord() in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html?highlight=ord#ord). In addition, I searched other sources, but I didn't find any mention of the problem:

[What is Python ord Function](https://www.pythonpool.com/python-ord/)

[Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)

[Cheatsheet Python 2 to 3](https://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html)

Am I looking at the correct spot? Or would the ord() function not be the problem in this case? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Encrypt is not working according to spec. It's supposed to return a string but returns a bytes object instead. Those are the same in py 2 but different in py 3

Comment: Also, `for key_id, c in enumerate(content):` was the way to go even in py2

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I changed the return from encrypt() and the first argument from decrypt() to bytes. I also include the enumerate() function in the strings. thanks for pointing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is not in `ord()` but in `binascii.unhexlify()`. In Python 2 it returns a string and if you index into that string you get a string of length 1, that you can call `ord()` on. But in Python 3 it returns a `bytes` and if you index into that, you get a small integer that you can't call `ord()` on, and don't need to.